# Find a pair of numbers to the 4th power equals to input number

Tags: c, algorithm

Receiving an input number, find an efficient algorithm to find if exist a sum 
 of pair of numbers in power of 4 which equals to this number. 
For example:

```
Input: val=337
```

```
x=3^4=81
```

```
y=4^4=256
```

```
81+256=337
```

Another example is:

```
val=641
x=5^4=625
y=2^4=16
val=x+y=641
```

I was trying to solve this problem using C code.

I thought about this question, and I just thought to iterate all the possible numbers that the power of 4 of them, will provide a number less than the requested input and check if the sum of all the possible numbers are match to this number.

It doesn't seem very efficient.
Please, can you help?
thanks

Comment: You are conflating two distinct problems - (a) choosing an appropriate algorithm and (b) implementing the chosen algorithm in C. The two are pretty much unrelated. Just concentrate on (a) for now.

Comment: How large can the input be?

Comment: Hint: all powers of 4 are of the form, in binary 1 00 00  ... 00.

Comment: @chux 3*3*3*3 = 81 => 1010001

Comment: @bruno that is not a power of 4, but 3 to the 4th power.  But seeing OP example code - looks like it is described wrong, but as you suggest.  Unclear then what OP wants.

Comment: raptor0102 Do you want a sum of _powers of 4_ or _numbers to the 4th power_?

Comment: @chux yes the title is wrong, but my English is wrong too and 
they cancel each other allowed me to understand well ^^

Comment: visibly for 337 the result is 3 and 4 because 3^4 + 4^4 is 337, so is not power of 4 but power 4

Comment: Review [Disproving Euler proposition by brute force in C](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/145221/29485) for efficient alternative.ideas to a similar, but more complex problem.

Comment: @chux I fixed the title, I want
numbers to the 4th power

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<math.h>

long long int binarySearch(long long int limit){
    long long int low = 1,high = sqrt(sqrt(limit));
    long long int mid = 0;
    long long int ans = 0;
    while(low <= high){
        mid = low + (high - low) / 2;
        long long int raiseToFour = mid * mid * mid * mid;
        if(raiseToFour > limit) high = mid - 1;
        else if(raiseToFour < limit){
            low = mid + 1;
            ans = mid;
        }else{
            ans = mid;
            break;
        }
    }

    return ans;
}

int main(void) {
    long long int sum = 337;
    long long int i;
    long long int left = 1, right = binarySearch(sum);
    while(left <= right){
        long long int leftFourthPower  = left * left * left * left;
        long long int rightFourthPower = right * right * right * right;
        if(leftFourthPower + rightFourthPower == sum){
            printf("%lld ^ 4 + %lld ^ 4 = %lld",left,right,sum);
            break;
        }else if(leftFourthPower  + rightFourthPower > sum){
            right--;
        }else{
            left++;
        }
    }


    return 0;
}
```

It gives:

```
3 ^ 4 + 4 ^ 4 = 337
```

- Well, do a binary search from `1` to `sqrt(sqrt(sum))` to find a number who is 4<sup>th</sup> power of some number closest to `sum`.
- Now, using 2 pointer approach(`left` and `right`, where `right` is the upper limit from binary search function), find the pair whose 4<sup>th</sup> powers add up to the given sum. If sum exceeds, we decrement `right` pointer and if it's less than the given sum, increment `left` pointer.
- Space complexity is **O(1)**.

Comment: Nice solution! I really liked it!

Comment: @vivek_23 The solution is working however: You binary search is not doing anything, it always returns the high number. The solution finds only the first answer, no others. It is not fast: for the number 635318657. it needs to loop the while 77 times (to find first answer).

Comment: @Aldert Yes, binary search is returning the highest number itself all the time, however, since it gets converted into int while storing after sqrt(), I found it better to trace down once again. The OP asked for `find if exist a sum of pair`, hence it returns only one solution. If you want to see all, remove the `break` and add `left++` and `right--` to it. The time complexity will be `sqrt(sqrt(sum))` in the worst case which is decent enough.

Answer (score 0):

A simple heuristic is checking values less or equal than `sqrt(sqrt(n))` for the input `n`. Hence the complexity of this algorithm would be `"choose 2 from  sqrt(sqrt(n))" = O(sqrt(n))`.

Answer (score 0):

**Solution 1: `O(n)` time & `O(n)` space**

*Pseudocode*

1. *Initialize a hash table with pre-computed values*: For each item `x`, store in a hash table `x^4`
2. *Search for pairs*: For each item `x`, check if `val-x^4` is in the hash table

If step 2 finds a match, then there exists a pair that satisfies the requirement.

*Complexity*

The complexity is `O(n)` for building the hash table and `O(n)` for scanning. Additionally, the additional space required is `O(n)`.

*Implementation*

For *c* implementation, it is possible to use [`unordered_set`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/unordered_set/unordered_set/).

- For simplicity, it is assumed that all the values are unique. If that's not guaranteed, a count of the values is required (to avoid `x^4+x^4=val` where `x` appears just once in the input).

**Solution 2: `O(n*log(n))` time & `O(1)` space**

*Pseudocode*

1. *Sort all input value in-place*: Sort the values of the array in ascending order
2. *Search for pairs*: For each `x`, binary search for `sqrt(val-x^4)`

If step 2 finds a match, then there exists a pair that satisfies the requirement.

*Comlpexity*

The complexity of sort is `O(n*log(n))`. Each binary search requires `O(log(n))` time and performed `n` times. Therefore, the overall time complexity is `O(n*log(n))`

*Implementation*

For *c* implementation, it is possible to use [`qsort`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/qsort/).

Answer (score 0):

This can be done fast by using the formula:

[image]

we can calculate the highest possible number to the power 4 , this is the start.
to minimize the for loop, we can end when we are at half of the number. Solution supports also other powers.
Full code below (C#)

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        const int raisedPow = 4;
        long num = 3262811042;

        Console.WriteLine("{0}", num);
        int start = (int) Math.Pow(Math.E, (Math.Log(num) / Math.Log(Math.E)) / raisedPow);
        int end = (int) Math.Pow(Math.E, (Math.Log(num/2) / Math.Log(Math.E)) / raisedPow);
        int y = -1;
        int stepCount = 0;

        for (int i = start; i>end;i--)
        {
            stepCount++;
            long rest = (long) (num - (Math.Pow(i, raisedPow)));
            int j = (int) Math.Round(Math.Pow(Math.E, (Math.Log(rest) / Math.Log(Math.E)) / raisedPow));
            if (rest - (Math.Pow(j, raisedPow)) == 0)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("{0} {1}", i, j);

                y = j;
            }
        }
        Console.WriteLine("steps {0}", stepCount);
        if (y == -1) Console.WriteLine("No Solution");

        Console.ReadKey();
    }
```